# Pidgin: suppress notifications for account or protocol

Tags: facebook, pidgin, jabber

I'm excited that Facebook Chat now easily plugs into Pidgin, but don't like getting all these notifications. Is there a way to suppress notifications for a single account or protocol?

Well, if it's a protocol solution, though, I'd still like notifications on Gmail, which is also XMPP. Interesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only sound settings I could find, were conversation based or global.

Workaround: Perhaps another instance of pidgin running muted?

http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#HowdoIrunmultipleinstancesofPidginonWindows

Couldn't find a ticket for it, if you really want that feature, I suggest asking the developers to add it: http://developer.pidgin.im/query (might have to sign up)